# Copying randomly generated keys to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that generates random codes distributed from https://www.sendowl.com when a customer purchases them, and then the codes are provided on the thank you page. My issue is that I want a button that copies all the codes and adding a line break. So far I got something that copies one code at a time but I can't figure out this one

This is the script I am using.

```html
<script>
function myFunction(val, event) {
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = val;
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy', false);
  inp.remove();
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Here the button to copy the codes. `{% for license in order.licenses %}{{ license.key }}{% endfor %}` is needed because it's what generates the codes.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('{% for license in order.licenses %}{{ license.key }}{% endfor %}')"class="btn btn-primary">Copy All Codes</button>
```

I'm a major noob when it comes to this so any help would be appreciated.

The codes are copied like this:
[image: screenshot of how codes are copied]

I want them to copy like this:
[image: screenshot of how I want to copy the codes]

Here is the screen shot of how the codes are distributed on the page after purchase
[purchase thank you page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVsth.png)

Below is the entire thank you page or receipt

```html
<p>Hi{% if order.receiver_name %} {{ order.receiver_first_name }}{% endif %},</p>

<p><br />Thanks for ordering from us. This email confirms your order of the following items:<br />{% for cart_item in order.cart.cart_items %}{{ cart_item.product.name }} x {{ cart_item.quantity }}<br />{% endfor %}</p>

<p>Your Order ID is {{ order.id }}{% if order.settled_gross %} and your payment has now cleared. A receipt has been emailed to you separately.{% endif %}</p>
<br>
<br>




{% assign product_types = order.cart.cart_items | map: 'product' | map: 'member_types' | flatten %}{% if product_types contains 'tangible' %}You have ordered tangible goods. These will be posted shortly and you will be notified once they have been dispatched.{% endif %}

{% if product_types contains 'digital' or product_types contains 'software' or product_types contains 'redirect' %}
{% if product_types contains 'software' %}


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('{% for license in order.licenses %}{{ license.key }}{% endfor %}')"class="btn btn-primary">Copy All Codes</button>


<br>
<br>
<table border="1">

  <tr><th> Name </th> <th> Code </th> <th> QR Code </th> <th> Copy </th>

<tr>{% for license in order.licenses %} <td>{{ license.product.name }}:</td>

<td>{{ license.key }}</td>  <td> <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl={{ license.key }} " /path/to/image.jpg /> </td> <td><button type="button" onclick="myFunction('{{ license.key }}')"class="btn btn-primary">Copy Code</button> </td> </tr>

{% endfor %}{% endif %}{% endif %}
</table>


{% if product_types contains 'service' %} You have ordered service goods. The merchant will be in contact to arrange the carrying out of these services.{% endif %}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Thanks,</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Liquid Realms</p>

<script>
function myFunction(val, event) {
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = val;
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy', false);
  inp.remove();
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Create a line break using `\n`

Comment: Example, `oldCode + "\n" + newCode`

Comment: Ive tried using the \n but i never got a result, I just end up breaking the code, is there a correct way to do it

Comment: Place an image of how this code appears to you on the page and add `console.log(val)` inside the `myFunction` function

Comment: After adding `console.log` within the function, run the copy command and see what is displayed on the console and provide it here

Comment: You posted a print showing how the codes are copied, but we need to see how the codes are displayed

Comment: @AksJacoves I updated my post with more info

Comment: @Rudu I tried that just now but breaks the rest of the code after it, it all turns red

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the `input` element that is created to receive all the code, because it is not possible to wrap the line as I answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I noticed is that you can't use `/n` when creating an element of type input, so use textarea when creating the function to copy all the codes, as in the example below:

I ended up creating a function called `copyAll` and it will go through its second column of the table (where the codes are) and copy them, then a textarea element will be created that will receive all the codes with a line break and then we can copy it

```html
<p>Hi{% if order.receiver_name %} {{ order.receiver_first_name }}{% endif %},</p>

<p><br />Thanks for ordering from us. This email confirms your order of the following items:<br />{% for cart_item in order.cart.cart_items %}{{ cart_item.product.name }} x {{ cart_item.quantity }}<br />{% endfor %}</p>

<p>Your Order ID is {{ order.id }}{% if order.settled_gross %} and your payment has now cleared. A receipt has been emailed to you separately.{% endif %}</p>
<br>
<br>




{% assign product_types = order.cart.cart_items | map: 'product' | map: 'member_types' | flatten %}{% if product_types contains 'tangible' %}You have ordered tangible goods. These will be posted shortly and you will be notified once they have been dispatched.{% endif %}

{% if product_types contains 'digital' or product_types contains 'software' or product_types contains 'redirect' %}
{% if product_types contains 'software' %}


<button type="button" onclick="copyAll()"class="btn btn-primary">Copy All Codes</button>


<br>
<br>
<table border="1">

  <tr><th> Name </th> <th> Code </th> <th> QR Code </th> <th> Copy </th>

<tr>{% for license in order.licenses %} <td>{{ license.product.name }}:</td>

<td>FIRST CODE</td>  <td> <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl={{ license.key }} " /path/to/image.jpg /> </td> <td><button type="button" onclick="myFunction('{{ license.key }}')"class="btn btn-primary">Copy Code</button> </td> </tr>
<tr>{% for license in order.licenses %} <td>{{ license.product.name }}:</td>

<td>SECOND CODE</td>  <td> <img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl={{ license.key }} " /path/to/image.jpg /> </td> <td><button type="button" onclick="myFunction('{{ license.key }}')"class="btn btn-primary">Copy Code</button> </td> </tr>

{% endfor %}{% endif %}{% endif %}
</table>


{% if product_types contains 'service' %} You have ordered service goods. The merchant will be in contact to arrange the carrying out of these services.{% endif %}
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Thanks,</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Liquid Realms</p>

<script>
function myFunction(val, event) {
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = val;
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy', false);
  inp.remove();
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}

function copyAll() {
  let trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
  let inp = document.createElement('textarea')
  let codes = ''
  trs.forEach((tr, index) => index > 0 && (codes += tr.querySelectorAll('td')[1].innerText + "\n"))
  document.body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = codes
  inp.select()
  document.execCommand('copy', false)
  inp.remove()
  alert('Copied \n' + codes)
  
}

</script>
```

Comment: OMG YES! it copied all the codes with a line break, you are amazing!